# Importing UsbSerialPort, Hexdump, SerialInputOutputManager in Android Studio

Tags: java, import, usb

I'm trying to use the 'mik3y/usb-serial-for-android' library in order to read a serial connection. When trying to use the example code, I get errors because of certain things that will not import.

Here are the import statements that I'm having issues with(I've replaced my name and project info  with dummy data):

```
import com.mycompany.johnsmith.driver.UsbSerialPort;
import com.mycompany.johnsmith.util.HexDump;
import com.mycompany.johnsmith.util.SerialInputOutputManager;
```

I receive the error: Cannot resolve symbol 'driver' for the first import, and Cannot resolve symbol 'util' for the other two.

I've installed the library as a dependency and all of my other imports work fine, but I'm still not sure if the issue is because of the library.

Comment: Why did you replace the package names?   You should use the package names in the original (mik3y) code.

Comment: The package used in the example code is: package com.hoho.android.usbserial.examples; but it says it does not correspond original file path